# Google Docs Link and Viewing PDF

Tags: google-docs

https://spreadsheets.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0Ap6NKDUcJz8sdHZjOWM1bkFxZ0wxUW9Bcnl3QmRsbGc&single=true&gid=0&output=pdf

The link above downloads the PDF, but I just want it to open up in the browser.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the output=pdf.

https://spreadsheets.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0Ap6NKDUcJz8sdHZjOWM1bkFxZ0wxUW9Bcnl3QmRsbGc&single=true&gid=0

Comment: You can use the viewer:  https://docs.google.com/viewer   for example: http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https%3A%2F%2Fspreadsheets.google.com%2Fspreadsheet%2Fpub%3Fkey%3D0Ap6NKDUcJz8sdHZjOWM1bkFxZ0wxUW9Bcnl3QmRsbGc%26single%3Dtrue%26gid%3D0%26output%3Dpdf   but I think you are talking about the browser using the pdf viewer.

Comment: I guess that could work, but yes I want the browser to open it.

Comment: which browser are you using (or your users will be using)?

Comment: I think the best you can do is download an addon:  https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/google-docs-viewer-pdf-doc-doc/

Comment: What about Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open pdf in browser without downloading pdf then below is the best way to do it :

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
String yoururl = https://spreadsheets.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0Ap6NKDUcJz8sdHZjOWM1bkFxZ0wxUW9Bcnl3QmRsbGc&single=true&gid=0&output=pdf;
yoururl= "https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + yoururl;
i.setData(Uri.parse(yoururl));
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want it to open in your browser, you need a PDF viewing plugin for your browser.
The same obviously holds true for your visitors as well.
It is the browser which determines what to do with files. (open or dowload)

Comment: That is not true.  You can either download or view the file.  It depends how it is sent to the browser.  I have Firefox and I can open PDFs.

Comment: It absolutely IS true. You can open PDFs in Firefox because you have a plugin. http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Opening%20PDF%20files%20within%20Firefox

Comment: Your question is also a duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293893/how-to-force-pdf-files-to-open-in-browser

Comment: I wasn't referring to the plugin part, but was referring to the  the last sentence.  The browser does not determine what to do with it.  You can send a response back of bytes which would download or display the pdf (depending if they have the plugin).  
"content-disposition:attachment" would save, while "content-disposition:inline" would display on the response.  Google is sending back bytes for an attachment causing me to save it, but I need it to send it back "inline" to display.