# TypeError: The header content contains invalid characters

Tags: javascript, node.js

below is my function to get file from my server writing in sailsJS.
When i try run this function, my console throw me this type of error:
`TypeError: The header content contains invalid characters`

In postman i send file in pdf format,

How content-type should look here?

```
fn: async function ({ id }, exits) {

    this.res.set('Content-disposition', `attachment; filename=${id}`, 'content-type', 'application/pdf')//here
    this.res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')

    const localPath = path.join(sails.config.custom.uploadDirectory, id)

    this.res.sendFile(localPath);
  }
```

**and how to open fle in a browser instead of download him to desktop?**

thanks in advance

Comment: From [link]https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition[/link] `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.jpg"` i think you are missing the "

Comment: Link appears broken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
fn: async function ({ id }, exits) {

res.set({
  'Content-disposition': `inline; filename="${id}"`,
  'content-type': 'application/pdf',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
})

const localPath = path.join(sails.config.custom.uploadDirectory, id)
this.res.sendFile(localPath);
 }
```

Comment: okay, thanks, it works, but in my previous version my file had to be open in the browser instead of downloading it to the desktop, do you know how to do it?

Comment: Thanks to @nicraft I updated to inline. You can upvote his and my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As per SailJS [Documentation here](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/response-res/res-set), you can pass in a single object argument (headers) to *set multiple header fields* at once, where the `keys` are the header field names and the corresponding `values` are the desired values.

I think you are not setting header values in right way.

It should be sending the complete object if setting multiple values:

```
res.set({
  'Content-disposition': 'attachment',
  'content-type': 'application/pdf',
  'filename':  'filename.pdf'
})
```

**[EDIT]:** In order to open the File in Browser, You should add

```
Content-Disposition: `inline;filename="${id}"`
```

Comment: As per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition)  doc,  Content-disposition header contains attachment as well as filename

Comment: okay, thanks, it works, but in my previous version my file had to be open in the browser instead of downloading it to the desktop, do you know how to do it?

Comment: to open it in browser I think you should add `Content-Disposition: inline;filename="myfile.pdf"` Check this answer here :  https://stackoverflow.com/a/35913510/9386929

Comment: @AymanArif, You are right. But the filename is always optional.

Comment: @nicraft can you update your post with function to open file in browser?

Comment: hmm.. looks like @AymanArif, already updated his answer and it got accepted. Can you please upvote mine at least?