# HTML force user to download PDF file from URL

Tags: javascript, html, url

I am getting server side URL to my HTML,on click of that URL PDF file is opening in browser itself,Since the PDF is larger Size I want to force the user to download it(saveas pop up)
Please help me

Comment: Use `Content-Disposition: attachment; ...` header.

Answer (score 8):

You don't need javascript to do this. In a modern browser you can simply do `<a href="somepathto.pdf" download="filename">`

Related post:

- [How to force files to open in browser instead of download (pdf)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293893/how-to-force-pdf-files-to-open-in-browser)

Comment: this is not working in safari. in safari pdf file open in tab can help me to resolved this?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the HTML5 attribute download :

```
<a href="link" download="filename"/>
```

You can also make a PHP page that will read the PDF and force the download, by using these functions :

```
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=filename.pdf');
exit(readfile(yourPDF));
```

(PHP is useful if you want to prevent the users to delete the download attribute, but it may be too much)

Answer (score 3):

Use the `download` attribute:

```
<a download="file.pdf">Link</a>
```

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#attr-hyperlink-download

Comment: I tried above approach,but the pdf file rendering in the browser itself

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
> <FilesMatch "\.(?i:pdf)$">   ForceType application/octet-stream  
> Header set Content-Disposition attachment </FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Interesting answer ! But you should specify that it must be put in htaccess. Also, he's just talking about one PDF so I don't think that this is the best way