# Open pdf link in new tab - jQuery

Tags: jquery, pdf, window.open

Is it possible to open a pdf file link in a new tab? I'm using `window.open(url, '_blank')` at the moment, however, this downloads the file to the computer rather than opening it in a new tab.

Comment: Which browser are you using? There may not be plugins to read the `pdf` file in the browser. You need to have the broswer configured to read the `pdf` files inside it. There is nothing wrong with the jS part.

Comment: Not sure that JQuery is required to do this. Here is one solution. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11894771/1111233

Comment: server could also be set to force downloads for pdf

Answer (score 0):

for opening in the tab **as inline rather than download** you have to set header from server as descripbed in http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html

**Now how to set?**
It depends on your server side implementation. Give more details about your environment like you using .net, php, java and what code is used to server files.

example for php

```
<?php
header("Content-type:application/pdf");

// It will be called downloaded.pdf
header("Content-Disposition:inline;filename='downloaded.pdf'");

// The PDF source is in original.pdf
readfile("original.pdf");
?>
```

Comment: if it's an already created pdf file why would you deliver it with php?

Comment: if its a already created pdf the you have to set Content-Disposition at webserver level for pdf files or just stream it with any application server after setting this.

Comment: there are other more efficient ways to do that