# Build Excel sheet in Java Servlet through Glassfish Server

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish

I referred to [Coreservlets](http://pdf.coreservlets.com/)

> My question is when i run following program, it starts to download(which shows nothing inside it)
>   rather than displaying as Excel sheet on the browser as what book shows.No Exceptions happened

[image]

This is the program,

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
       // processRequest(request, response);
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
        PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
        out.println("\tQ1 \tQ2 \tQ3 \tQ4 \tQ5");
        out.println("Apples \t1 \t2 \t3 \t4 \t5");
        out.println("Oranges \t1 \t2 \t3 \t4 \t5");       
    }
```

I'm using Netbeans IDE with Glassfish 4.1 server which comes with Netbeans itself.Same time i' can't even build PDF's too.Am i missing plugin or something else?

Comment: What problem do you have? Do you have some exception or just doesn't see Excel sheet in browser?

Comment: my problem is, when i start to run program,it just get downloaded.No exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you desire is only possible, if browser is able to open the file inside the browser window. The browser needs MS Excel installed and a plugin to open MS Excel inside the browser window (this is similar to running flash in browser - it does not work until you install the flash plugin). I don't know if such a plugin is available for chrome or firefox, as applications from Microsoft are not behaving friendly to other applications.

If all this is in place, there is a high chance you will get desired behavior. If not, you might need to add a `Content-Disposition: inline` into the HTTP header in the response, as described here: [How to force files to open in browser instead of download (pdf)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293893/how-to-force-files-to-open-in-browser-instead-of-download-pdf#answer-11894771)

Like this:

```
response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename='apples_oranges.xls'");
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you use Internet Explorer with Windows with instaled Microsoft Office like in book? This example may not work in all browsers (Chrome, Mozila and so on).

Comment: Yep, it may be problem. Try to use  Internet Explorer

Comment: not working either,what do you mean by "installed Microsoft Office"?I have installed it on computer.