# How can i show a document in iframe using ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

In asp.net mvc project how can i work iframe to show a document file?
I tried to do below the code like that,but when i run the project file has download...why??

```
 public FileStreamResult GetPDF()
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(Server.MapPath(@"~/File/SegmentAdd.txt"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            return File(fs,"application/pdf","SegmentAdd.txt");         
        }

      <iframe src="@Url.Action("GetPDF","Home")"  width="90%" height="90%"></iframe>
```

Comment: This depends on the browser settings and the server http headers. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293893/how-to-force-files-to-open-in-browser-instead-of-download-pdf for more details.

Comment: i don't understand now what should i do?if i use like that...
            return File(fs,"application/pdf","SegmentAdd.txt");

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code, however it still depends on the browser, does your browser contains a plugin to read pdf files? If it has, then most probably your code will work, but if your browser does not have the plugin then it will fallback to just downloading the pdf.

Comment: Bon Macalindong,
I already plugin pdf reader into my chrome browser,but it does not work.It's always downloaded and doesn't show file.Qhat should i do...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your code as follows

```
public FileStreamResult GetPDF()
{
     FileStream fs = new FileStream(Server.MapPath(@"~/File/SegmentAdd.txt"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
     return File(fs, "text/plain");
}
```

Actually the content type of .txt file is

> text/plain

I hope this will help you

**UPDATE**

Inorder to know the content type of each file types Please refer [MIME Type list](http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html)

Comment: Thank you,Jayaraj.K
It works.
But one question when file type like .pdf/.doc or etc. what should be the content type?

Comment: It depend upon your file which you are trying to show. Please refer http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html,  MIME Type column you can find content type to be used for each file.

Comment: Thank you very much Jayaraj.K

Comment: Hey Jayaraj,how r you?
i have a problem in MapPath(" ");

when i get file name from database how can i map in the filestream and how can i show on iframe?

Comment: What problem you are facing in MapPath. Does it throws any error, If so post the issue as another question.

Comment: Hey Jayaraj,
I can not post new qus cz i have already post another qus.
If u don't mind can i describe this prob via mail or social any site or ur personal blog?

Comment: Jayaraj,i already post my qus,please see this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37961161/how-can-show-document-file-in-iframe-when-i-get-the-file-name-from-database

Comment: Hey Jayaraj did u see this problem what i post ?