# How can show document file in iframe when i get the file name from database?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

How can show document file in iframe when i get the file name from database?My database table name is File and my viewmodel is MyFileModel.

```
    public ActionResult Create(HttpPostedFileBase file)
       {         
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Files.Add(new File()
                {
                    FileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName)
                });
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            var error = "Sorry not save";
        }
        return Content("");
    }

     public FileStreamResult GetPDF()
        {
            var file = db.Files.Single(s => s.Id == 1);
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(Server.MapPath(file.FileName), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            return File(fs, "application/pdf");
            //return View(Server.MapPath("~/File/SegmentAdd.txt"));
            //return File(fs,"text/plain");
        }

   <div id="frame">
    <iframe src="@Url.Action("GetPDF","Home")" width="900px" height="500px"></iframe>
  </div>
`
```

Comment: May I know what you are saving in FileName field just the name or full path of the uploaded file. If your are saving only the file name with the above case you will be getting an error I guess.

Comment: I have saved the file name.Actually i want to save the document file with file name.

Comment: Are you saving any physical file in your filesystem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer which I am posting is all on an assumption, I do not have clear picture of your solution.
If you are not saving a physical file try to save it in a folder and then save the name in the DB OR try to save the entire path in the DB.

**Method 1** :

If you are saving the file  in a folder say ***File*** best way is to add a key in the web.config(.config file which is at the root) as follows

```
<add key="FilePath" value= "~/File/"/>
```

and then modify your C# code as follows

```
public FileStreamResult GetPDF()
        {
            var file = db.Files.Single(s => s.Id == 1);
            string fileName = file.FileName;
            string filePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePath"] + fileName;
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(Server.MapPath(filePath), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            return File(fs,"text/plain"); // "text/plain" if your file content-type is text file
            //return View(Server.MapPath("~/File/SegmentAdd.txt"));
            //return File(fs,"text/plain");
        }
```

**Method 2** :

If you are saving the entire path then it makes coding much more simpler and you need not change the code you have written, just go ahead with the same.

Hope this would help you.

Comment: Hi Jayaraj,
Sorry i did not mention what i want.I want to save physical file into database then i want to display file from database by the query single by single.
Thank you.

Comment: Physical file into database means? I couldn't get you. Do you mean in bytes?

Comment: Is any way to save physical file into database?Byte or other approach
idon't know how?

Comment: Before that let me ask you why you are prefering to save the physical files into database. If you save files into database tremendouse amount of memory will be taken. If that is an issue, it is better to follow the method 1 in my post.

Comment: I understand Jayaraj,
i will do method-1 wise 
thank you.

Comment: If your question is been answered please mark the post as answer :))

Comment: Upps sorry for that :D

Comment: Hi Jayaraj,
How r u?I have a problem in ajax call to controller.Please check it and give me a solution?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38036782/how-to-ajax-call-to-controller-with-value-pass/38036946#38036946

Answer (score 0):

I think the way the pdf will open is dependent on the browser that the user uses.

You probably need something like: https://pdfobject.com/.

Good luck!