# How to Ajax call to controller with value pass?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

How can i get value from ajax to mvc controller method in '`FileStreamResult`' in mvc?I want to pass value from `<a href="#" id="fileId">@Model[i].ToString()</a>` to controller by ajax.

Controller

```
      public ActionResult Index()
    {
        IEnumerable<VmFile> model = _manager.fileName();
        return View(model);
    }
    public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        try
        {
            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {

                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/File/"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);
                _manager.UploadFile(file, path.ToString());
            }
            ViewBag.Message = "Upload successful";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Upload failed";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
 public FileStreamResult GetFile(int Id)
{
    string fileName = _manager.FileName(Id);
    string filePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePath"] +  fileName;
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(Server.MapPath(filePath), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    return File(fs, "application/pdf");
}
```

FileManager

```
   public string FileName (int id)
    {
        string fileName = _unitOfWork.FileRepository.Get(r => r.Id ==   id).Select(f => f.Name).First();
        return fileName;
    }

  public IEnumerable<VmFile> fileName()
    {
        var file = _unitOfWork.FileRepository.Get();

        var model = from r in file
                    select new VmFile
                    {
                        Id = r.Id,
                        Name = r.Name,
                        ThanaId =r.ThanaId,
                        RoadId = r.RoadId,
                        Url = r.Url,
                        UpLoadDate = r.UpLoadDate,
                        FCategoryId = r.FCategoryId, 
                        FileType = r.FileType
                    };

        return model;
    }
   public void UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file,string path)
    {

        string fName = file.FileName;
        string[] typ = fName.Split('.');//Regex.Split(fName, @".");
       File newFIle = new File
        {
            Name = fName,
            Url = path,
            FCategoryId = 1,
            ThanaId = 23201,
            RoadId = 12,
            FileType = typ[1],
            UpLoadDate = DateTime.Now
        };
        _unitOfWork.FileRepository.Insert(newFIle);
        _unitOfWork.Save();
    }
```

VmFile

```
public class VmFile
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public Nullable<short> BridgeId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> UpLoadDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> FromChain { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> ToChain { get; set; }
    public string FileType { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> FCategoryId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ThanaId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> RoadId { get; set; }
 }
```

View

```
  @model IEnumerable<RSDMS.ViewModel.VmFile>
@{
Layout = null;
}
 <html>
 <head>
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
<title>Index</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="header" class="container">
            <h2>Document Module</h2>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div id="h2" class=" panel panel-primary "><h4       id="h4">Document Type</h4></div>
                <div id="form" class=" panel-body">
                    <form role="form">
                        <label class="checkbox-inline">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="">A-Road Related
                        </label>
                        <label class="checkbox-inline">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="">B-Road+Structure Relate
                        </label>
                        <label class="checkbox-inline">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="">C-
                        </label>
                        <label class="checkbox-inline">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="">Option 1
                        </label>
                        <label class="checkbox-inline">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="">Option 2
                        </label>
                        <label class="checkbox-inline">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="">Option 3
                        </label>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="listpanel" class="panel-primary">
                <h1>List Panel</h1>
                <div id="file">
                    <table>
                        <th>File Name</th>
                      @foreach (var file in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <li>
                                 <a href="#" id="fileId">@file.Name</a>
                                    </li>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                    <br />
                }
                    </table>
                </div>
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Document", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
        {
        <label class="btn btn-block btn-primary">
                Browse &hellip; <input type="file" name="file" id="file" style="display: none;">
                    </label>
            <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Upload">
        }
            </div>

            <div id="frame" class="panel-body">
                <div id="frame">
                    <iframe src="@Url.Action("GetFile", "Document")" width="900px" height="500px"></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>

    <style>
        #h2 {
            background-color: lightblue;
            height: 40px;
        }
#h4 {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
#header {
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px;
}
#frame {
        float: right;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
#listpanel {
        float: left;
}
    </style>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(e)  {
            // var p = { Data: $('#fileId').val() };
            //var currentDataItem = this.dataItem(this);
            //id = currentDataItem.Id;
            alert($('#fileId').attr('id'));
            var p = { Data: $('#fileId').val() };
            alert(p);
            var id = $('#fileId').text();
            alert(id);
            $('#fileId').click(function () {
                $.ajax(
                {
                    //url: '@Url.Action("GetFile", "Document")?id=' + id,
                    url: '/Document/GetFile',
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {Id:id},
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                    },
                    error:function(e)
                    {
                    }
                });
            })
        });

</script>
```

Comment: I have certain queries to be asked, Is the ActionResult method a post method and have you referred jQuery plugin in bundle.config or any where in your application

Comment: Yes,this actionresult i mean FileStreamResult GetFile() is a httppost method and i have already add this script
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: If you have added jQuery plugin, let me know the version of the plugin.

Comment: One thing i tell you,
I want to pass value from ajax to GetFile method when i click one of the list of File name list >
<a href="#" id="fileId">@Model[i].ToString()</a>
and this the list of File and it has individual Id and name.I am showing the name of file and click the name it pass the Id from ajax to controller.But it does not call the controller.What should i do?

Comment: And what is this Model[i] and you haven't assigned any ID into your view to pass it into your method. and from where do you get this ID from.Please specify these in detail.

Comment: Please modify the question with these details.

Comment: I am collecting the file name from database.This db has filename,Id,filepath etc.Model[i] is the name of file list collecting from db.

Comment: Is the script tag been added manually or in the BundleConfig.cs in App_Start folder

Comment: Yes i have added manually into index file.

Comment: Please check the BundleConfig.cs in App_Start folder if there is any jQuery file has been specfied in it. If so please remove the script tag that you have added mannually and check if it works

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript code should be wrapped in a jQuery load function, like this:

```
 $(function () {

 //Paste all your java script here

 });
```

That was the only change I made on my side and the AJAX call to GetFile in the Document controller is now working

Answer (score 0):

As Denis Wessels said you have to enclose jquery code inside document ready block

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var currentDataItem = this.dataItem(this.select());
    id = currentDataItem.Id;
    var p = { Data: $('#fileId').val() };
    $('#fileId').click(function () {
      $.ajax(
      {
          url: '@Url.Action("GetFile", "Document")?id=' + id,
          //url: '/Document/GetFile',
          type: "POST",
         // data: {Id:id},
          success:function(data)
          {
          },
          error:function(e)
          {                    
          }
      });
    })
});
```

Comment: It does not call to controller.An error shows "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined".Please what else?

Comment: You might forgot to add jquery file `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I already add this script but it does not get perametar value to controller.

Comment: What id you have to pass to that method.If you have to pass #fileId text then you should use id = $('#fileId').text();

Comment: Id alws selected by the first value but when i click another it does not work,
One thing i tell you,
I want to pass value from ajax to GetFile method when i click one of the list of File name list >
<a href="#" id="fileId">@Model[i].ToString()</a>
and this the list of File and it has individual Id and name.I am showing the name of file and click the name it pass the Id from ajax to controller.But it does not call the controller.What should i do?

Comment: If you have multiple name list then you should use class or uniq id for each filename.And you should give more code to understand

Comment: You can give here or you also can edit your question

Answer (score 0):

First all let me correct certain mistakes in your code. In view haven't passed any id that could be passed in the action method. So either in the FileManager class change the returntype of  GetData method as

`Dictionary<int,string>`

OR

create a model class say FileManagerModel as follows

```
public class FileManagerModel
{
  public int ID {get;set;}
  public string FileName{get;set;}
}
```

and change the return type as

```
List<FileManagerModel>
```

accordingly change the model in the view as

```
@model Dictionary<int, string> // If the return type is Dictionary<int,string>
```

and then in the view change your for loop as follows

```
@foreach(var file in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#" id="fileId" data-id="@file.Key">@file.Value</a>
                                </li>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <br />
                    }
```

and also change your GetFile method as follows

```
public FileStreamResult GetFile(int? id)
        {
            string fileName = "IFrameTest.txt";
            var t = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePath"];
            string filePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePath"] + fileName;
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(Server.MapPath(filePath), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            return File(fs, "text/plain");
        }
```

add nullable int arguement in your method as on page load your id will be null.

As the method by default is HTTPGET method in your Ajax call you need to make changes as follows

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e)  {
        var id = $('#fileId').text();
        $('#fileId').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var id = $(this).data("id");
            $.ajax(
            {
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetFile", "Document")',
                    type: "GET",
                    data: { id: id },
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                    },
                    error:function(e)
                    {
                    }
                });
            })
        });

</script>
```

On doing these changes it worked for me .I hope this will rectify your issue

**UPDATE**

If you are using IEnumerable pass the Id in the data attribute as

```
<a href="#" id="fileId" data-id="@file.Id ">@file.Name</a>
```

Comment: I have already created VmFile which is your FileManagerModel.Is it necessary to create another method?I can not understand why i use Dictionary<int,string> in view?Please let me clear about that.

Comment: But you haven't used the class anywhere. The model (@model) that you declaring in the view is the return type of the model that you are returning from Index method. Since you are not assigning any data id from the model and you are just trying pass a ID from no where to the GetFile method via Ajax I just suggested you to use Dictionary<int,string>

Comment: I have edited something change from Controller and FileManager.
Please check now.

Comment: Your model is of IEnumerable<VmFile> type change model in the view as @model IEnumerable<VmFile>

Comment: What should be id pass by data-id it can not show.So how can i pass id from 
      <a href="#" id="fileId">@file.Name</a>

Comment: pass your ID from VMFile

Comment: I have edited in index getting IEnumerable<RSDMS.ViewModel.VmFile> which has all attribute in VmFile include Id.It doesn't work yet to pass Id and doesn't call controller. :(

Comment: Can you please check with the changes that I have suggested. It should work actually.It worked fine for me.

Comment: I already mention what i have changed.If it is alright or not.Please check my index.Is it ok?"data-id" does not exist into <a .....>...</a>?When i retreiving Id from IEnumerable<VmFile>

Comment: I do not know what you are trying to do. I do not get you by saying "data-id" does not exist into <a .....>...</a>".

Comment: You suggested me to pass Id by data-id from anchor tab when applying by dictionary<int,string>.
Now i'm doing by IEnumerable<> and now how can i pass Id from VmFile to controller by ajax.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: By the way @MehediIslam. SOF do not have people who does work for you. You should take effort and try  and practise googling things. ;))