# Moqui: opening an attachment instead of downloading it

Tags: browser, httpresponse, moqui

How can I instruct the browser to open an attachment (PDF or JPEG) in a new tab instead of downloading it? I suppose it is done by sending a specific response - I found a thread discussing on setting the response's parameters. Is there a way to do it in Moqui?

For info, this is the above-mentioned thread:
[How to force files to open in browser instead of download (pdf)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293893/how-to-force-files-to-open-in-browser-instead-of-download-pdf)

-----------------------------added 06.10.2016----------------------------

I am experiencing a strange behavior.

There is a form list with these parameters `<form-list name="InvoiceList" list="invoiceList" skip-form="false" multi="true">`.

In row actions I call a service which loads invoiceContentLocation, should there be one: `<service-call name="mantle.account.InvoiceServicesEnhancements.get#InvoiceContentToDisplay" in-map="[invoiceId:invoiceId]" out-map="contentInfo"/>`.

There is a field, a link which calls a transition, which purpose is to open the content in a separate tab. This is the field: `<field name="invoiceContentLocation">
                <default-field title="">
                    <link url="openContent"
                          condition="contentInfo.invoiceContentLocation"
                          icon="glyphicon glyphicon-file"
                          parameter-map="[invoiceContentLocation:contentInfo.invoiceContentLocation]"
                          link-type="anchor-button"
                          target-window="_blank"
                          tooltip="Open attachment of the invoice."
                    />
                </default-field>
            </field>`

And the transition: `<transition name="openContent" read-only="true">
        <parameter name="invoiceContentLocation"/>
        <actions>
            <log message="Location ${invoiceContentLocation}." level="info"/>
            <if condition="invoiceContentLocation!=null">
                <script>ec.web.sendResourceResponse(invoiceContentLocation, true)</script>
            </if>
        </actions>
        <error-response type="none"/>
        <default-response type="none"/>
    </transition>`

The content is always correctly opened in a new tab, but sometimes an exception occurs. Even for the same content file (of a single invoice), I have experienced both scenarios.

> 22:23:51.965  INFO 455896770-19           o.moqui.i.e.EntityFacadeImpl Found entities in 46 files in 19ms
>   22:23:51.965  INFO 455896770-19           o.moqui.i.e.EntityFacadeImpl Found 0 view-entity definitions in database (DbViewEntity records)
>   22:23:52.181  INFO 455896770-19           o.moqui.i.s.ScreenRenderImpl apps/AccountantScreen/Accounting/Invoice/FindInvoiceNAF in 359ms (text/html;charset=utf-8) session 19abbna66thi7zula8mifowqt
>   22:23:54.575  INFO 455896770-12           o.moqui.i.c.LoggerFacadeImpl Location dbresource://mantle/content/invoice/IMP_INV_918/content_100052/918_Fega_Frost_1162736029.pdf.
>   22:23:54.646  INFO 455896770-12              o.moqui.i.c.WebFacadeImpl Streamed 946939 bytes from location dbresource://mantle/content/invoice/IMP_INV_918/content_100052/918_Fega_Frost_1162736029.pdf
>   22:23:54.656  INFO 455896770-12           o.moqui.i.s.ScreenRenderImpl Transition apps/AccountantScreen/Accounting/Invoice/FindInvoiceNAF/openContent in 81ms, type none response
>   22:23:54.673  INFO 455896770-16           o.moqui.i.c.LoggerFacadeImpl Location dbresource://mantle/content/invoice/IMP_INV_918/content_100052/918_Fega_Frost_1162736029.pdf.
>   22:23:54.680 ERROR 455896770-16                      o.m.i.a.XmlAction Error running groovy script (org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException): 
>   1 : import org.moqui.impl.StupidUtilities
>   2 : import java.sql.Timestamp
>   3 : // these are in the context by default: ExecutionContext ec, Map context, Map result
>   4 :     ec.logger.log("info", """Location ${invoiceContentLocation}.""", null)
>   5 :     if (invoiceContentLocation!=null) {
>   6 : 
>   7 :     // begin inline script
>   8 :     ec.web.sendResourceResponse(invoiceContentLocation, true)
>   9 :     // end inline script
>   10 :     }
>   11 : 
>   12 : // make sure the last statement is not considered the return value
>   13 : return;
>   14 :

org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:197) ~[jetty-io-9.3.11.v20160721.jar:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.flush(WriteFlusher.java:420) ~[jetty-io-9.3.11.v20160721.jar:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.write(WriteFlusher.java:313) ~[jetty-io-9.3.11.v20160721.jar:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint.write(AbstractEndPoint.java:140) ~[jetty-io-9.3.11.v20160721.jar:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$SendCallback.process(HttpConnection.java:741) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.processing(IteratingCallback.java:241) ~[jetty-util-9.3.11.v20160721.jar:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.iterate(IteratingCallback.java:224) ~[jetty-util-9.3.11.v20160721.jar:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.send(HttpConnection.java:521) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.sendResponse(HttpChannel.java:706) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.write(HttpChannel.java:755) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHttpOutputInterceptor$GzipBufferCB.process(GzipHttpOutputInterceptor.java:384) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.processing(IteratingCallback.java:241) ~[jetty-util-9.3.11.v20160721.jar:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.iterate(IteratingCallback.java:224) ~[jetty-util-9.3.11.v20160721.jar:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHttpOutputInterceptor.gzip(GzipHttpOutputInterceptor.java:146) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHttpOutputInterceptor.write(GzipHttpOutputInterceptor.java:115) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:179) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:163) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:415) ~[?:?]
    at org.moqui.impl.StupidUtilities.copyStream(StupidUtilities.groovy:268) ~[moqui-framework-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at org.moqui.impl.context.WebFacadeImpl.sendResourceResponseInternal(WebFacadeImpl.groovy:735) ~[moqui-framework-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at org.moqui.impl.context.WebFacadeImpl.sendResourceResponse(WebFacadeImpl.groovy:718) ~[moqui-framework-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at org.moqui.impl.context.WebFacadeImpl$sendResourceResponse.call(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at FindInvoiceNAF_xml_transition_openContent_actions.run(FindInvoiceNAF_xml_transition_openContent_actions:8) ~[script:?]
    at org.moqui.impl.actions.XmlAction.run(XmlAction.groovy:66) [moqui-framework-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at org.moqui.impl.screen.ScreenDefinition$TransitionItem.run(ScreenDefinition.groovy:698) [moqui-framework-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at org.moqui.impl.screen.ScreenRenderImpl.recursiveRunTransition(ScreenRenderImpl.groovy:222) [moqui-framework-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at org.moqui.impl.screen.ScreenRenderImpl.recursiveRunTransition(ScreenRenderImpl.groovy:216) [moqui-framework-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at org.moqui.impl.screen.ScreenRenderImpl.recursiveRunTransition(ScreenRenderImpl.groovy:216) [moqui-framework-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at org.moqui.impl.screen.ScreenRenderImpl.recursiveRunTransition(ScreenRenderImpl.groovy:216) [moqui-framework-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at org.moqui.impl.screen.ScreenRenderImpl.recursiveRunTransition(ScreenRenderImpl.groovy:216) [moqui-framework-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at org.moqui.impl.screen.ScreenRenderImpl.recursiveRunTransition(ScreenRenderImpl.groovy:216) [moqui-framework-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at org.moqui.impl.screen.ScreenRenderImpl.internalRender(ScreenRenderImpl.groovy:332) [moqui-framework-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at org.moqui.impl.screen.ScreenRenderImpl.render(ScreenRenderImpl.groovy:159) [moqui-framework-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at org.moqui.impl.webapp.MoquiServlet.doScreenRequest(MoquiServlet.groovy:82) [moqui-framework-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at org.moqui.impl.webapp.MoquiServlet.service(MoquiServlet.groovy:56) [moqui-framework-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [moqui.war:3.1.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:837) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1689) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:225) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1676) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:461) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:524) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:319) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:253) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_92]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev(SocketDispatcher.java:55) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:148) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:504) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:177) ~[jetty-io-9.3.11.v20160721.jar:9.3.11.v20160721]
    ... 62 more
22:23:54.686  WARN 455896770-16      o.moqui.i.c.TransactionFacadeImpl Transaction rollback. The rollback was originally caused by: Error running transition in [http://localhost:8080/apps/AccountantScreen/Accounting/Invoice/FindInvoiceNAF/openContent]
org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:197) ~[jetty-io-9.3.11.v20160721.jar:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.flush(WriteFlusher.java:420) ~[jetty-io-9.3.11.v20160721.jar:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.write(WriteFlusher.java:313) ~[jetty-io-9.3.11.v20160721.jar:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint.write(AbstractEndPoint.java:140) ~[jetty-io-9.3.11.v20160721.jar:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$SendCallback.process(HttpConnection.java:741) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.processing(IteratingCallback.java:241) ~[jetty-util-9.3.11.v20160721.jar:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.iterate(IteratingCallback.java:224) ~[jetty-util-9.3.11.v20160721.jar:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.send(HttpConnection.java:521) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.sendResponse(HttpChannel.java:706) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.write(HttpChannel.java:755) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHttpOutputInterceptor$GzipBufferCB.process(GzipHttpOutputInterceptor.java:384) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.processing(IteratingCallback.java:241) ~[jetty-util-9.3.11.v20160721.jar:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.iterate(IteratingCallback.java:224) ~[jetty-util-9.3.11.v20160721.jar:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHttpOutputInterceptor.gzip(GzipHttpOutputInterceptor.java:146) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHttpOutputInterceptor.write(GzipHttpOutputInterceptor.java:115) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:179) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:163) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:415) ~[?:?]
    at org.moqui.impl.StupidUtilities.copyStream(StupidUtilities.groovy:268) ~[moqui-framework-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at org.moqui.impl.context.WebFacadeImpl.sendResourceResponseInternal(WebFacadeImpl.groovy:735) ~[moqui-framework-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at org.moqui.impl.context.WebFacadeImpl.sendResourceResponse(WebFacadeImpl.groovy:718) ~[moqui-framework-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at org.moqui.impl.context.WebFacadeImpl$sendResourceResponse.call(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at FindInvoiceNAF_xml_transition_openContent_actions.run(FindInvoiceNAF_xml_transition_openContent_actions:8) ~[script:?]
    at org.moqui.impl.actions.XmlAction.run(XmlAction.groovy:66) ~[moqui-framework-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at org.moqui.impl.screen.ScreenDefinition$TransitionItem.run(ScreenDefinition.groovy:698) ~[moqui-framework-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at org.moqui.impl.screen.ScreenRenderImpl.recursiveRunTransition(ScreenRenderImpl.groovy:222) ~[moqui-framework-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at org.moqui.impl.screen.ScreenRenderImpl.recursiveRunTransition(ScreenRenderImpl.groovy:216) ~[moqui-framework-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at org.moqui.impl.screen.ScreenRenderImpl.recursiveRunTransition(ScreenRenderImpl.groovy:216) ~[moqui-framework-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at org.moqui.impl.screen.ScreenRenderImpl.recursiveRunTransition(ScreenRenderImpl.groovy:216) ~[moqui-framework-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at org.moqui.impl.screen.ScreenRenderImpl.recursiveRunTransition(ScreenRenderImpl.groovy:216) ~[moqui-framework-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at org.moqui.impl.screen.ScreenRenderImpl.recursiveRunTransition(ScreenRenderImpl.groovy:216) ~[moqui-framework-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at org.moqui.impl.screen.ScreenRenderImpl.internalRender(ScreenRenderImpl.groovy:332) [moqui-framework-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at org.moqui.impl.screen.ScreenRenderImpl.render(ScreenRenderImpl.groovy:159) [moqui-framework-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at org.moqui.impl.webapp.MoquiServlet.doScreenRequest(MoquiServlet.groovy:82) [moqui-framework-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at org.moqui.impl.webapp.MoquiServlet.service(MoquiServlet.groovy:56) [moqui-framework-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [moqui.war:3.1.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:837) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1689) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:225) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1676) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:461) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:524) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:319) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:253) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_92]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev(SocketDispatcher.java:55) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:148) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:504) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:177) ~[jetty-io-9.3.11.v20160721.jar:9.3.11.v20160721]
    ... 62 more
22:23:54.693  WARN 455896770-16      o.moqui.i.c.TransactionFacadeImpl Transaction rollback for [Error running transition in [http://localhost:8080/apps/AccountantScreen/Accounting/Invoice/FindInvoiceNAF/openContent]]. Here is the current location: 
org.moqui.BaseException: Rollback location
    at org.moqui.impl.context.TransactionFacadeImpl.rollback(TransactionFacadeImpl.groovy:426) ~[moqui-framework-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at org.moqui.impl.context.TransactionFacadeImpl.rollback(TransactionFacadeImpl.groovy:409) ~[moqui-framework-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at org.moqui.impl.screen.ScreenRenderImpl.internalRender(ScreenRenderImpl.groovy:334) ~[moqui-framework-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at org.moqui.impl.screen.ScreenRenderImpl.render(ScreenRenderImpl.groovy:159) ~[moqui-framework-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at org.moqui.impl.webapp.MoquiServlet.doScreenRequest(MoquiServlet.groovy:82) ~[moqui-framework-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at org.moqui.impl.webapp.MoquiServlet.service(MoquiServlet.groovy:56) ~[moqui-framework-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) ~[moqui.war:3.1.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_92]
22:23:54.694 ERROR 455896770-16                   o.m.i.w.MoquiServlet Internal error processing request: null
org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:197) ~[jetty-io-9.3.11.v20160721.jar:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.flush(WriteFlusher.java:420) ~[jetty-io-9.3.11.v20160721.jar:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.write(WriteFlusher.java:313) ~[jetty-io-9.3.11.v20160721.jar:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint.write(AbstractEndPoint.java:140) ~[jetty-io-9.3.11.v20160721.jar:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$SendCallback.process(HttpConnection.java:741) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.processing(IteratingCallback.java:241) ~[jetty-util-9.3.11.v20160721.jar:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.iterate(IteratingCallback.java:224) ~[jetty-util-9.3.11.v20160721.jar:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.send(HttpConnection.java:521) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.sendResponse(HttpChannel.java:706) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.write(HttpChannel.java:755) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHttpOutputInterceptor$GzipBufferCB.process(GzipHttpOutputInterceptor.java:384) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.processing(IteratingCallback.java:241) ~[jetty-util-9.3.11.v20160721.jar:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.iterate(IteratingCallback.java:224) ~[jetty-util-9.3.11.v20160721.jar:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHttpOutputInterceptor.gzip(GzipHttpOutputInterceptor.java:146) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHttpOutputInterceptor.write(GzipHttpOutputInterceptor.java:115) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:179) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:163) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:415) ~[?:?]
    at org.moqui.impl.StupidUtilities.copyStream(StupidUtilities.groovy:268) ~[moqui-framework-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at org.moqui.impl.context.WebFacadeImpl.sendResourceResponseInternal(WebFacadeImpl.groovy:735) ~[moqui-framework-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at org.moqui.impl.context.WebFacadeImpl.sendResourceResponse(WebFacadeImpl.groovy:718) ~[moqui-framework-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at org.moqui.impl.context.WebFacadeImpl$sendResourceResponse.call(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at FindInvoiceNAF_xml_transition_openContent_actions.run(FindInvoiceNAF_xml_transition_openContent_actions:8) ~[script:?]
    at org.moqui.impl.actions.XmlAction.run(XmlAction.groovy:66) ~[moqui-framework-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at org.moqui.impl.screen.ScreenDefinition$TransitionItem.run(ScreenDefinition.groovy:698) ~[moqui-framework-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at org.moqui.impl.screen.ScreenRenderImpl.recursiveRunTransition(ScreenRenderImpl.groovy:222) ~[moqui-framework-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at org.moqui.impl.screen.ScreenRenderImpl.recursiveRunTransition(ScreenRenderImpl.groovy:216) ~[moqui-framework-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at org.moqui.impl.screen.ScreenRenderImpl.recursiveRunTransition(ScreenRenderImpl.groovy:216) ~[moqui-framework-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at org.moqui.impl.screen.ScreenRenderImpl.recursiveRunTransition(ScreenRenderImpl.groovy:216) ~[moqui-framework-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at org.moqui.impl.screen.ScreenRenderImpl.recursiveRunTransition(ScreenRenderImpl.groovy:216) ~[moqui-framework-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at org.moqui.impl.screen.ScreenRenderImpl.recursiveRunTransition(ScreenRenderImpl.groovy:216) ~[moqui-framework-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at org.moqui.impl.screen.ScreenRenderImpl.internalRender(ScreenRenderImpl.groovy:332) ~[moqui-framework-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at org.moqui.impl.screen.ScreenRenderImpl.render(ScreenRenderImpl.groovy:159) ~[moqui-framework-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at org.moqui.impl.webapp.MoquiServlet.doScreenRequest(MoquiServlet.groovy:82) [moqui-framework-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at org.moqui.impl.webapp.MoquiServlet.service(MoquiServlet.groovy:56) [moqui-framework-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [moqui.war:3.1.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:837) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1689) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:225) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1676) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:461) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:524) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:319) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:253) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589) [moqui.war:9.3.11.v20160721]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_92]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev(SocketDispatcher.java:55) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:148) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:504) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:177) ~[jetty-io-9.3.11.v20160721.jar:9.3.11.v20160721]
    ... 62 more
22:23:54.699  WARN 455896770-16      o.moqui.i.c.TransactionFacadeImpl Rollback only not set on current transaction, status is STATUS_NO_TRANSACTION
22:23:54.699 ERROR 455896770-16                   o.m.i.w.MoquiServlet Error rendering internal-error error screen, sending code 500 with message: null
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error rendering screen [component://webroot/screen/webroot.xml]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the details for this take a look at the simple MoquiFopServlet.groovy file.

Basically if you pass a 'filename' parameter then it will add a Content-Disposition header with attachment and the given filename. If there is no filename parameter the Content-Disposition header will be the simple inline sort and the PDF will show in the browser (well, depending on the browser...).

Comment: I looked into the groovy file. But I used a code similar to the one in the openContent transition of Invoice's ContentSection. Changed a bit. I added it to my original question.