# How do I make a pdf open in a browser in a new tab instead of getting a download link?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<p>
    <a href="mypdf.pdf" target="_blank">Open</a>
</p>
```

It is always giving me a download link! How should I open it a new tab?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force files to open in browser instead of download (pdf)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293893/how-to-force-files-to-open-in-browser-instead-of-download-pdf)

Comment: It should open if your browser has pdf viewer.