# Need to download pdf file on client/user's machine instead of server machine in Spring Boots or MVC

Tags: java, file, spring-mvc, pdf, itext

I have written the code to generate the pdf file in server machine, but my requirement is that when user clicks on some button/url on the site in that case he should be able to see that pdf file in new tab of the browser or should be downloaded in his machine directly.

Here is the code which I have written

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/downloadPDF", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void downloadPDF() 
            throws FileNotFoundException, DocumentException {

        final String DEST = "column_width_example.pdf";

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        //Below method returns the data which will be convert in table format for pdf file
        String dataForPDFFile = rowForUserCompetency(sb, "name");

        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate());
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(DEST));
        document.open();
        float[] columnWidths = { 2.5f, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3 };
        String[] lines = dataForPDFFile.toString().split("\\n");

        Font fontRow = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 10, Font.NORMAL);

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(columnWidths);
        table.setWidthPercentage(100);
        table.getDefaultCell().setUseAscender(true);
        table.getDefaultCell().setUseDescender(true);

        for (String string : lines) {
            String[] cellData = string.toString().split(",");
            for (String header : cellData) {
                PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();

                cell.setPhrase(new Phrase(header.toUpperCase(), fontRow));
                table.addCell(cell);
            }
            table.completeRow();

        }

        document.add(table);
        document.close();

    }
```

And this code is generating the pdf file on that server so normal user won't be able to see the file in his machine, so can someone guide me what should be the changes in above code.

Comment: So what's the problem/error?

Comment: this code is generating pdf file on the server, so user won't be able to see the file

Answer (score 2):

You need to manage the HTTP response.

```
public void downloadPDF(HttpServletResponse response) {
  // Set the headers for downloading or opening your document
  response.setContentType("application/pdf");
  response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"user_file_name.pdf\"");
  ...
  // Write directly the output stream.
  PdfWriter.getInstance(document, response.getOutputStream());
  ...
  // Build your document as ever.
}
```

Comment: it worked for me perfectly, is there any way that I can open same pdf file in new tab instead of downloading it ??

Comment: Have a look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293893/how-to-force-files-to-open-in-browser-instead-of-download-pdf

As to open it in another window, that's depends on the target of link / submit you use (it's pure HTML on the client side) you cannot force it from server.