# Did pdf open in the browser

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, pdf, html4

I need to know if the pdf opened in the browser or in a separate reader.

I'm working on a website that will open a pdf file in a new window, but some people knowingly or unknowingly set their browser to open the pdf in an Adobe or third party reader.  If the pdf did not open in the window I opened for it, I would like to close that window.

How do I know if the pdf did not open in the browser?

Comment: You can add the `download` attribute to the `<a href>` tag to force a download, but it may not be supported in all browsers.

Comment: download is html5 and I want the pdf to open in the window.  I just want to know if it didn't because someone had their browser set to open in a reader.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293893/how-to-force-files-to-open-in-browser-instead-of-download-pdf)

Comment: Is this a Java or Javascript question?  (Note they are not the same thing.)

Comment: I do not want to force it to download.  I want the pdf to open in the browser, but some people have their browser set to always download.  I need to know if the pdf opened in the browser.

Comment: Java is used to create the pdf.  Javascript and Jquery is used to open a window and display the pdf.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do that, for good reasons: privacy, security.

I don't know about the requirement of your project, if you really want to keep control, you need to stay in the HTML, CSS, JS land, not pdf.