# Reading PDF file with php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have been using `codeigniter framework`. It was going very with everything except that I can't read my `pdf` files. When I do try reading, It downloads or saves it instead. I have tried a lot of solutions but didn't work.

**Controller**

```
public function read($name)
{

    $url = base_url().'uploads/'.$name;
    header('Content-type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.$name.'"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
     @readfile($url);

}
```

Comment: set the `Content-Length` too : `header('Content-Length:' . filesize($url));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How can you read a pdf file? If by read you mean to read characters in the pdf file then you need an OCR library to do the same. You can find different libraries like:

http://www.fpdf.org/

Comment: and how do you implement this library?

Comment: You can start with: 
<?php
require('fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
$pdf->Output();
?>

Comment: There are examples present on the site :)

Answer (score 0):

checkout:
[How to force files to open in browser instead of download (pdf)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293893/how-to-force-files-to-open-in-browser-instead-of-download-pdf)

also if this doesn't help you try using a library like mpdf or dompdf they have good documentation on how to export files to browser or to save it etc

https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf