# How to open a remote link of PDF file using Javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

For example, I have a pdf file link like this:
https://boliden.chemsoft.eu/BlackBoxInterface.aspx?output=doc&id=20647&filesekv=85858&filename=Zinc_2015-06-01_English.pdf. 

If I create a link
 `<a href="https://boliden.chemsoft.eu/BlackBoxInterface.aspx?output=doc&id=20647&filesekv=85858&filename=Zinc_2015-06-01_English.pdf">Pure zink, Zinc_2015-06-01_English.pdf</a>`
When I click this link, instead of showing the pdf file, the browser download it automatically. 
**So is there any way to open that PDF file using js?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force files to open in browser instead of download (pdf)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293893/how-to-force-files-to-open-in-browser-instead-of-download-pdf)

Comment: Because the link downloads the PDF automatically, nothing you can do about that ... if you had a static PDF file then what you're doing would work and the PDF file would be automatically opened. If you add `target="_blank"` to your `<a>` then it would also be opened in another window rather then in current one.

Comment: thanks you all, i got it

Answer (score 0):

You could force the display of the PDF by using a library like [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/).

Otherwise, the user's browser will decide to either download or display the PDF document (assuming you do not send a `force-download` header).

`-- EDIT`

Following Barmar's comment, you indeed need to remove the `Content-disposition: attachment` header to let the browser decide.

Comment: It looks like the server is sending `Content-disposition: attachment`, which forces a download.

Comment: Thank nicovank and barmar. i will check it