# Force PDF file download in browser

Tags: html, pdf, http-headers

I have headers which force a file download, rather than viewing it in the browser but I need to give that option. I've looked at several posts on Stack Overflow which answer this question (eg [How to force files to open in browser instead of download (pdf)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293893/how-to-force-files-to-open-in-browser-instead-of-download-pdf)) but I am still not getting the desired result, so I wanted to check if I'm missing something.

Here are my headers to force a download

```
    $file = 'file.pdf';
    $filePath = 'path/to/file.pdf';

    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Length: 20000");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Type:file");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="$file"');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

    readfile($filePath);
```

And here are the header to try and display the file in the browser

```
    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Length: 20000");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Type:file");
    header('Content-Disposition:inline; filename="$file"');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

    readfile($filePath);
```

So the only change is the content-disposition header.

However, I am still just being shown the markup in the browser (see image).

[image]

Any ideas?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are still using `inline` for content-disposition when you want to instruct browser to perform a download. Try use `attachment` instead.

more detais: [Content-Disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition)

Comment: Sorry - my mistake, it shoudl be attachment (and is in my code - have corrected the above). In any event, the issue is not with forcing a download it's showing in the browser