# <iframe src="file.pdf"> now downloading rather than displaying

Tags: javascript, html

As of this morning we have a handful of users experiencing a change in behavior on our very old website.

We have HTML that looks like this:

```
<iframe id="I1" style="HEIGHT: 495px" name="I1" marginWidth="0" 
        marginHeight="0" frameBorder="no"
        width="100%" height="500"></iframe>
```

And javascript that looks like this:

```
document.getElementById('I1').src = Request.QueryString("p").Item(1);
```

That code is launched with a URL that looks like this:

```
https://example.com/DisplayPDF.aspx?p=../Images/TMP_1234.pdf&l=673&ver=3.1.1.33
```

The intention of that code is to display the .pdf file in the iframe.

It has worked that way for years.

This morning for some users it is popping up the "View Downloads" dialog and asking to Save or Open the file.  One can Save or Open, but this change in behavior is confusing our less technically savvy users.

The obvious suspect is a windows/browser update; the system administrator tells me he backed out the updates.

To me it is irrelevant if it was caused by an update I need to figure out a solution for those users that will update and do not have the means to back it out.

I ran in F12 mode with the browser to see any issues. there was nothing unusual.  The website works fine in Chrome.

Here is the behaviors we are seeing:

1. Chrome - Consistently opens quickly in the browser popup window.
2. IE 11 - HTML popup window opens but it stay blank.  A "View Downloads" window opens where I can view the .pdf.
3. IE 11 - HTML popup window opens and stays blank.  No "view downloads" windows opens.
4. IE 11 - HTML popup window opens and takes quite some time to populate with the .pdf file.

I posted this on stack because I'm hoping for a code solution to make this work on all browsers. I'm guessing I got the downvote because this might have been viewed as a inappropriate for stack.

Comment: I think this has to do with the version of the browser! I know that chrome does something with the PDF viewer/download in the last 3 versions :-/

Comment: Add `console.log(Request.QueryString("p").Item(1));` and see what is output.

Comment: The browser may have changed it's default when the returned pdf doesn't have a response-header `Content-Disposition`.Explicitly setting a response header of the pdf to `Content-Disposition:inline` will probably fix it. Furthermore check that response header `Content-Type: application/pdf` is set instead of the deprecated (and perhaps due to a browser update unsupported) `Content-Type: application/x-pdf`

Comment: You said "some users" this means only one thing, those users has no pdf reader plugin in there web browsers.

Comment: @Geert-Jan That sounds like a good guess.  is there a way for me to do that in the .js or .html file?  The reason I ask is I have control of those.  I will have to involve others if I change the server config.

Comment: As @SaidbakR wrote, or those users browsers are configured to download pdf (or open externally) instead of showing inline.

Comment: @michaelPotter: no. You need to change the server config. However, you can inspect the response-headers of the pdf in something like chrome inspector, to see if they're okay

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293893/how-to-force-files-to-open-in-browser-instead-of-download-pdf) is related question to header settings..

Comment: Check if the header `Content-Type: application/pdf` is being sent from your file server.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem and **geert-jan**'s comment with setting a response header of the pdf to

```
Content-Disposition:inline
```

really fixed it.