# How to make IE open a PDF with a single click?

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, pdf

I'm creating a web page with a link to a PDF file.

I have been asked to set up the link so that the user can click the link *once* and see the PDF.  Here's what I've tried so far:

One way is to simply put `<a href="XXX.pdf" target="_self">PDF</a>` in the HTML

The other is to make the link trigger Javascript: `window.open("XXX.pdf", "_self");`

Either way, IE always shows a prompt that says, "Do you want to open or save XXX.pdf", so that the user must click again to open the file.  I get similar results in both Chrome and Firefox.

I have been asked to set up the web site so that the user can open the PDF with *one* click.  How can I do this?  I suspect that maybe I need to set the response headers on the web server a certain way.  My web stack is ASP.net

Comment: do you have access to the php calling the file?

Comment: As I stated in the question, I'm using ASP.net, but yes, I have access to both the client-side and server-side code.

Comment: IE has activex document for this, but client needs to install a PDF viewer that support the activex document technology, and needs to support the tab's bitness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the solution.  I feel silly saying this, but it turns out that my server was programmed to send a header specifying that the browser should download the file and give it a specific name.  Once I took that out, everything worked fine.  IE is able to open the PDF in the same tab, or a new tab, just like any other content.

In short, I just needed to get rid of:

```
result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
{
    FileName = $"my_file.pdf"
};
```

Answer (score -2):

Couple of interesting links:

User side:
https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/display-pdf-in-browser.html

PHP:
[How do I force files to open in the browser instead of downloading (PDF)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293893/how-do-i-force-files-to-open-in-the-browser-instead-of-downloading-pdf)

ASP:
http://dotnetcode143.blogspot.in/2012/05/open-pdf-file-in-new-browser-tab-using.html

HTML:
Some links are saying to set the target to "_blank"

Comment: Thanks for these links, but none of the linked solutions worked for me.  I get the same old "Do you want to open or save" prompt.