# Opening a pdf in a new tab, instead of downloading it from within a function

Tags: javascript, file, pdf, browser, download

within a function of my code I am trying to open a new tab with pdf.
I precisely want the pdf to be shown in the browser, vs it being downloaded, but the browser are instead downloading.
I have disabled my browsers settings to download pdf files vs showing them, so that can't be the issue.

The relevant part of the code is simple:

```
if (isMobile) {
  newTab.location = redirectUrl;
} else {
  window.location = redirectUrl;
}
```

It works for mobile, but downloads it on desktop.
The url is a pdf that is stored on a AWS S3 cloud.

**Is there a way to ensure the pdf is opened in the browser, vs downloading it?**

Comment: So, what research have you done to try to find the answer?

Comment: I googled 'open pdf in new tab instead of download' and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293893/how-do-i-force-files-to-open-in-the-browser-instead-of-downloading-pdf) was the first link.

Comment: I should have been more precise.
My function is running on the front-end, the url is returned by an AWS S3 server, which I have no access to. The link you gave only has solutions by changing the header, which I can't do