# Prevent Force Download of AWS S3 Files Django

Tags: django, boto3, django-storage

I am using

```
storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage
```

storage backend to upload files in my django project.

field declaration in model:

```
document = models.FileField(upload_to=s3_directory_path.user_directory_path)
```

user_directory_path

```
def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    # TODO: Try to include this along with check filetype on the request object
    document = instance.document
    mime = magic.from_buffer(document.read(), mime=True)
    extension = mimetypes.guess_extension(mime, strict=False)
    file_name = str(uuid.uuid4()) + extension
    document.seek(0)
    return os.path.join("users", str(instance.user.id), file_name)
```

The saving of the document works perfectly fine, but the link which is generated force downloads the file. How can i avoid that?

Comment: You can add an iam policy to for this. Maybe make the bucket private or add deny on `s3:getobject`?

Comment: Could you please clarify, which link forces the download? The return value of `user_directory_path`?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11894771/219519) to a general question about forcing file downloads via HTTP response headers. See also the [MDN docs about `Content-Disposition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition).

Can you show us the response headers you get when visiting the document URL?
It would be interesting to see how S3 delivers your files.

If you cannot change the headers in S3, you have the option to write a Django view that proxies the file download. Alternatively, configure your webserver (i.e. NGINX) to act as a proxy and set the required headers).

For Django, [this section of the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#setting-header-fields) will show you how to set the headers.

```py
response = HttpResponse(
    document, 
    headers={
        'Content-Type': mimetype,
        'Content-Disposition': f'attachment; filename="{document.name}"',
    }
)
```