# Download file apk from server and install it

Tags: android, flutter

I have feature check newest version the application, if current version is lesser than version in server it will show dialog to update the application like this .

[image]

in above update, if i click **copy link and download**, it will copy url and open the browser,after that download .apk from url server i already setting.

it's work , but i want make it more efficient. I want if i click the button , it will download .apk from server and show the progress download without open the browser. How can i do this ? 
Thank's

Answer (score 1):

**Play Store**

It's not a feature currently available to my knowledge. In apps I develop, I can check the version number and block the user from using the app via a dialog, but provide a link to the Play Store, so they can update to the latest version.

However, Android 11 provides Inline Updates, which provides a more streamlined experience.

Check out [In-App Updates](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates)

Android 11 as of this date is currently in preview. To use the APIs you will have to use a platform channel to call natively from Flutter.

**Side loading**

Check out [Install Application programmatically on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4604239/540339)

You will have to use http to download the APK to external storage, then call these APIs via a [platform channel](https://buildflutter.com/native-apis-platform-channels/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can make it to where when you click a button, a file (any format including APK) is downloaded to the Downloads/Files folder of the user's device.

However, it is something that is handled by the server that is storing the files.

For example, if you tap on [this link](https://qa-bgrsguide.bgrs.ca/api/cm/kc/content/file/1627?download=true), it will automatically download a PDF file on your Android phone or on your browser, even if PDFs generally open inside your browser.

There is a few suggestions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293893/how-do-i-force-files-to-open-in-the-browser-instead-of-downloading-pdf) on how to do it, including setting "Content-Disposition: attachment" or "Content-Type: application/octet-stream"