# is it possible to open the .pdf file in web browser instead of downloading?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

As of now, im using the signed url technique to get the files from GCS

```
BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(BlobId.of(bucketName, gcsFolderPrefix + fullFileName)).build();
URL url = storage.signUrl(blobInfo, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES,Storage.SignUrlOption.withV4Signature());
```

After hitting the generated signed url in the browser , its getting downloaded but I need to open the file,I tried by adding the response headers also like below:

```
response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "multipart/form-data");
response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,"inline;filename=" + fileId.toString()+".pdf");
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I force files to open in the browser instead of downloading (PDF)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293893/how-do-i-force-files-to-open-in-the-browser-instead-of-downloading-pdf)

Comment: No, after the hitting the signed url in the browser its getting downloaded directly instead of opening

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the metadata of your blob in GCS before generating the SignedUrl

```
BlobInfo blobinfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(BlobId.of(bucketName, gcsFolderPrefix + fullFileName))
//Add the correct content type
.setContentType("application/pdf")
.build();

// Update the Blob
storage.update(blobinfo);

URL url = storage.signUrl(blobInfo, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES,Storage.SignUrlOption.withV4Signature());
```

Comment: Great!!!!. After updating the blob object it got worked , Thank u so  much