# To disable the forced file download

Tags: .htaccess

there is a problem-you need to open the .pdf file on the link in the browser. Now it's downloading and I don't understand why. The link does not have the "download" attribute in. htaccess found forced download https://pastenow.ru/9a61d44d122398fa48e5e521fc8f0391 and commented it out, added "AddType". But it didn't help. How to specify a forced opening .the pdf in the browser?

Comment: You cannot, it is the choice of the browser (and client OS) to determine what to do.  Most browsers nowadays will default to open a PDF, but maube this can be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293893/how-do-i-force-files-to-open-in-the-browser-instead-of-downloading-pdf

Comment: thanks for the link, just on the dev site the browser opens. And on the" production " site loads. This behavior occurs in all browsers. So I'm trying to figure out why this is happening and how to fix it. I tried it like this https://pastenow.ru/734551287b2377a55912655916676c90 it didn't help

Comment: Semi colon ( `:`) missing after `Content-Disposition`