# Open PDF file in new browser window in ASP.NET Core 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, pdf, asp.net-core-mvc

I have created the pdf file in the MVC Controller in ASP.NET Core 3. I am returning the `FileStreamResult` from this controller.
I want to open the PDF in a new browser window.

Below is the HTML Code -

```
<a asp-controller="Score" asp-action="ViewScore" target="_blank" >View PDF</a>
```

Below is the controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ViewScore()
{
      /*Created the pdf doc*/
      MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
      stream = doc1.Stream;

      string contentType = "application/pdf";
      string fileName = "sample.pdf";

      var file = File(stream, contentType, fileName);
            
      return file;
}
```

I am getting the downloading option for the pdf file. Instead of that, I want to open the pdf in the new browser window.

Comment: Note that `[asp.net]` and `[asp.net-core]` are mutually exclusive (ASP.NET is for .NET Framework projects, whereas ASP.NET-CORE is for .NET Core projects). Note also that, if you're using ASP.NET Core, there is a .NET Core MVC tag for that (`[asp.net-core-mvc]`).

Comment: It seems like you might need to find an ASP.NET/ASP.NET Core way of setting "inline" (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293893/how-do-i-force-files-to-open-in-the-browser-instead-of-downloading-pdf)).

Comment: You cannot decide how a PDF will be opened on a client PC. Once downloaded you have no control over it.

Answer (score 3):

Don't specify `fileDownloadName` if you want to open the pdf in a new tab.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ViewScore()
{
     /*Created the pdf doc*/
     MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
     stream = doc1.Stream;

     string contentType = "application/pdf";
     string fileName = "sample.pdf";

     var file = File(stream, contentType);
        
     return file;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Adi, if my solution can work, could you please [accept it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), thanks!