# Flutter url_launcher - how to force download pdf link?

Tags: flutter, url-launcher

I'm trying to force download a pdf file when the link is clicked.
For some links, it works. But other pdf links, it just shows pdf in the browser.
I'd appreciate if you could help! Thanks

Comment: Show your attempt of code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st way**

it's managed from the URL. I think. you can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293893/how-do-i-force-files-to-open-in-the-browser-instead-of-downloading-pdf). because that download URL contains some header based on that browser performing an action.

show file in browser:

```
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="filename.pdf"
```

download file in browser

```
Content-Type: application/pdf Content-Disposition: attachment;
filename="filename.pdf"
```

so basically you need to manage this in URL.

**2nd way**
you can also directly download files from URL

Web download option

```
import 'dart:html' as html;
void downloadFile(String url) {
   html.AnchorElement anchorElement =  new html.AnchorElement(href: url);
   anchorElement.download = url;
   anchorElement.click();
}
```

If you want to Download and Save files from URL without external libraries.
mobile platform

```
Future<String> downloadFile(String url, String fileName, String dir) async {
     HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
     File file;
     String filePath = '';
     String myUrl = '';
            
   try {
          myUrl = url+'/'+fileName;
          var request = await httpClient.getUrl(Uri.parse(myUrl));
          var response = await request.close();
         if(response.statusCode == 200) {
                    var bytes = await consolidateHttpClientResponseBytes(response);
                    filePath = '$dir/$fileName';
                    file = File(filePath);
                    await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
              } else
                    filePath = 'Error code:'+response.statusCode.toString();
            } catch(ex){
                  filePath = 'Can not fetch url';
      }
            
       return filePath;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Vishal! Really helpful 