# How to display a PDF without downloading

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a PDF like like this:

```
"http://centraldata.s3.amazonaws.com/.....pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=...."
```

which I get from an api call. Then I pass it into an  link so that users can click and download it.

```
<a href={pdfUrl} />
```

So, my question is, is there a way to let user view the PDF without downloading it? Except passing the Url into an  tag, I don't know if there is any other way to use this link

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I force files to open in the browser instead of downloading (PDF)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293893/how-do-i-force-files-to-open-in-the-browser-instead-of-downloading-pdf)

Answer (score -2):

just use this

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf', '_blank', 'fullscreen=yes'); return false;">MyPDF</a>
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work because the url is a download link. So I tried the code and click on it, it open a new tab with blank page, and the file is still downloaded.

Comment: @ThiNguyen you have to ask your backend person to make file viewable also so.