# Open PDF on Firefox

Tags: html, pdf, firefox

I've worked on my website for month, and after a while I've restarted.
And I have a page where I can upload file and open them in a viewer.
With Chrome I don't have any problem, everything works just fine!
But when I try it on Firefox, it just downloaded.

Is there a way to open PDF on mozilla instead on downloading?

Thanks for anyone who can clarify this for me!

Comment: Are you wanting to do this on your own browser personally or are you wanting to do this from the server end for every browser that visits your PDF?

Comment: from the server end @Martin

Answer (score 0):

## HTTP Headers to force browsers to open a file instead of downloading it:

[How do I force files to open in the browser instead of downloading (PDF)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293893/how-do-i-force-files-to-open-in-the-browser-instead-of-downloading-pdf)

## If you want to set your own Firefox to open PDFs:

By default, Firefox should display PDFs inline unless your website has explicitly told it to download the file rather than open it.

If you go to the Firefox URL bar and type in `about:config` and press enter, then once you pass the warning notice at the top you will need to type in `browser.download.open_pdf_attachments_inline` and change this setting from default `false` to `true`.

You should also confirm that `browser.shell.setDefaultPDFHandler.onlyReplaceBrowsers` setting is also set to `true`.

Exit and then retry. PDFs should now open inside the browser itself rather than any 3rd party reader.

Read more [here from Mozilla](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/view-pdf-files-firefox-or-choose-another-viewer).

## If you want to set so any browser that visits your website views PDF inline:

[Recommended way to embed PDF in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html?rq=1)

Comment: I would bet he's wanting to do this from the server side, not configuring his browser. The info is available all over the internet, too.

Comment: @Rob yes the thought had occurred to me. I'm actually likely to delete this as I found on my own Firefox that it opens PDFs by default so maybe OPs has been changed

Comment: And if his question is about how to configure Firefox, that makes it off topic here, too, as it's not a programming quesiton.

Comment: @Rob I think I've covered all the bases in my answer there 

Comment: I'm using a computer at my workplace so i dont know if some settings were touched; but anyway I dont need it just for my PC but also for anyone who visit my site. I tried looking online but just found ways locally. I'm gonna look through the last link to told me. Thanks @Martin