# How to convert an OutputStream created by OpenPdf (java library) to readable and downloadable via http response (http4s, scala) pdf document?

Tags: javascript, java, scala, http4s, openpdf

I want my http-service (Scala, http4s, Ember) to receive a http-request, create a pdf document using OpenPdf library and make a http-response to user's browser with this pdf document. User should see pdf inside the browser or download it.

I have a route for GET request:

```scala
case GET -> Root / "pdf" / IntVar(book) => getBookF(book) match {

        case Some(bookF: BookF) =>
          val b = createPdfSingleBook(bookF)
          Ok(b, Header.Raw(CIString("Expires"), "0"),
            Header.Raw(CIString("Cache-Control"), "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"),
            Header.Raw(CIString("Pragma"), "public"), Header.Raw(CIString("Content-Length"), s"${b.length}"),
            Header.Raw(CIString("Content-Type"), "application/pdf"))

        case None => NotFound()
```

```scala
def createPdfSingleBook(bookF: BookF): String = {

    val monolingualBook = new Document()

    val pdfOutputFile: FileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(s"${book.id}.pdf")
    val baos: ByteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()

    val baosWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(monolingualBook, baos)
    val pdfWriter: PdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(monolingualBook, pdfOutputFile)

    monolingualBook.open()

    //Content of a pdf-document

    val res = Base64.getEncoder.encodeToString(baos.toByteArray)

    monolingualBook.close()
    baosWriter.close()
    pdfWriter.close()

    res
  }
```

There are two OutputStreams in the code. FileOutputStream works and I have a pdf document saved on my disk. I want the same result in the browser: same document opened in the browser. Please, help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I force files to open in the browser instead of downloading (PDF)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293893/how-do-i-force-files-to-open-in-the-browser-instead-of-downloading-pdf)

Comment: Unfortunately, no. 
My problem is to convert val baos: ByteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream() to readable pdf. I as a user can download something as a pdf document, but then I open it there is an error: this array of bytes is not a valid pdf document.
I collect bytes from this function val b = createPdfSingleBook(bookF) and make a http-response Ok(b, headers). But this file in the end is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Have your PDF book return the raw `Array[Byte]` rather than a `String`:

```
def createPdfSingleBook(bookF: BookF): Array[Byte] = {

    val monolingualBook = new Document()

    val baos: ByteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    val baosWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(monolingualBook, baos)

    monolingualBook.open()

    //Content of a pdf-document
    // Use baosWriter here....

    monolingualBook.close()
    baosWriter.close()

    baos.toByteArray
  }
```

Return 200 OK with the body being the pdf and the content-type set:

```
val pdfData :Array[Byte] = createPdfSingleBook(...)

Ok(pdfData, Header("Content-type", "application/pdf"))
```

Comment: baosWriter has type PdfWriter and there is no method toByteArray on it. If I invoke this method on baos: ByteArrayOutputStream I see the same error then I try to open this pdf document.

Comment: Sorry it should be `baos` the `ByteArrayOutputStream` object. Basically don't turn the `Array[Byte]` into a string here: `val res = Base64.getEncoder.encodeToString(baos.toByteArray)`

Comment: I have already tried to get this ByteArrayOutputStream as String and as Array[Byte]. Same result: pdf document is broken, I can't open it. But pdf document that made by the same function via FileOutputStream is valid and opens well.

Comment: You've got two `pdfWriters`: `baosWriter` and `pdfWriter`. Maybe you need to remove pdfWriter and change all the commands that use `pdfWriter` to use `baosWriter` instead. Then you're actually writing your document into the `baos: ByteArrayOutputStream`.

Comment: Remove any calls to `pdfOutputFile` and make sure all the document is being created through `baosWriter`.